# How do I use a sudo command line to copy a folder into the system files?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, gnome-terminal

Specifically, my "themes" folder has been corrupted (my fault), and I need to replace the entire folder with a backup that I made.

I will add a finalized answer once I can.

Answer (score 4):

It would go something like this:

```
sudo cp -r /path-to-backup/themes /usr/share/
```

`cp` is the copying command

`-r` is there for recursiveness

Comment: I just tried that, and the directory was created, but the themes will not show up in the appearance settings.

Comment: Have you logged out/in?

Comment: OK I found the problem, it's rather embarrassing, but I created a themes folder in the themes folder. What's the command to delete a folder? (sorry I'm new to this)

Comment: Ah, to delete, run `sudo rm -r /usr/share/themes`, note, no slash at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem has been resolved, and I will post an updated answer with instructions after the minimum time has passed.

Comment: If you feel that @mikewhatever answer helped you to fix the issue. Please mark the answer as accepted answer by clicking on the grey tick mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A very elegant form is using `-a` option, it will recurse as `-r`, but will keep all attributes of the files, particularly permissions, and symlinks underreferenced:

```
sudo cp -a /path-to-backup/themes /usr/share/
```

In another words, "When performing the copy, attempt to preserve as much of the original file structure, attributes, and associated metadata as possible." ([citation source](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucp.htm))

Answer (score 0):

Passing the command to execute to `sudo` without any additional arguments will execute it as root.

```
sudo cp ...
```